# Issue setting up baremetal NGINX Ingress controller for Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress, ingress-controller, nutanix

I have a baremetal Kubernetes cluster running on Nutanix. However during the process of setting up the ingress controller i have had issues with it picking up an external IP address. Im reasonably new to Kubernetes and trying to debug this but cant figure out whats wrong.

Following [this](https://platform9.com/learn/v1.0/tutorials/nginix-controller-via-yaml) article i ran the following commands:

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v0.44.0/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml
```

The above command to setup the ingress controller, rbac, service accounts etc

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v0.44.0/deploy/static/provider/baremetal/deploy.yaml
```

And this command i believe should setup the service with the non internally networked IP, or the IP to which the Ingress rules would be applied against, and therefore my applications managed.

However what ends up being created is as follows.
[image: no external ip]

I've also tried using port-forwards on the Kubernetes cluster and can use the associated containers, so i know they are definitely functioning. I just can't seem to get an External-IP associated with the ingress controller, and cant find any resources online saying there is a setting i may not have enabled. Could anyone please help?

Comment: The service in the screenshot is of type `NodePort`. A svc of that type does not get an external IP. You need one of type `LoadBalancer` and in addition something like metallb, as Nataraj wrote. See also https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ExternalIP will get populated once there is an rule for the traffic routing from outside to k8s network.  This can be done by attaching an external reachable load balancer to ingress controller service.  Few options are [MetalLB](https://metallb.universe.tf/), [PureLB](https://purelb.gitlab.io/docs/) and [OpenELB](https://github.com/openelb/openelb) etc.,  Based on your requirement you can choose one.

Comment: Thanks, i ended up using an ingress controller, and routing to the nodeport via a HA proxy.